Download links for issue attachments
I am currently looking at creating download links for attachments to issues in a BIM360 project.
I´ve made it work for most of the attached files (pdf, photos, images) but there are also docx attachments and those get stored differently from what I can tell.
The attachment urn for a docx file looks like this: "urn:adsk.wipemea:dm.lineage:MSBYTyDcQXq6LeIoY8HnHw", while the urn for pdf and photos look like this: "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.emea.2/2decef01-65b5-4022-8855-54036e4d7cd7.pdf".
Is it possible to create a signed url for the docx file? And if so, can you give an example?
UPDATE! The issue here seems to be that these attachments are actually folders and not files. How can I handle such a case where I want to download the files in attached folder instead?

If you have the folder id you can use the Data Management, GET folder contents API: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/ to access the files
